# Gunicorn not able to run server

Tags: django, ssl, nginx, https, gunicorn

I am running the command `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 app.wsgi`. But server is not running and also not accepting any request from the browsers . It should atleast show `using TensorFlow backend`
as I it shows when i run the command.

`python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

Gunicorn shows just this only. 
`[2019-05-13 08:59:53 +0000] [9693] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
[2019-05-13 08:59:53 +0000] [9693] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (9693)
[2019-05-13 08:59:53 +0000] [9693] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2019-05-13 08:59:53 +0000] [9696] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9696`

On running `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

```
Performing system checks...

Using TensorFlow backend.
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
```

Comment: why should it show that message? That message comes from django logging? your django logging should go to file when running gunicorn. Also what tells you that the server isn't listening to incoming connections on port 8000? How do you check that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://codeinthehole.com/tips/console-logging-to-stdout-in-django/ on how to configure Django logging in your settings file.